# Most efficient way to weight and sum a number of matrices in Fortran

Tags: performance, fortran

I am trying to write a function in Fortran that multiplies a number of matrices with different weights and then adds them together to form a single matrix. I have identified that this process is the bottleneck in my program (this weighting will be made *many* times for a single run of the program, with different weights). Right now I'm trying to make it run faster by switching from Matlab to Fortran. I am a newbie at Fortran so I appreciate all help.

In Matlab the fastest way I have found to make such a computation looks like this:

```
function B = weight_matrices()
n = 46;
m = 1800;
A = rand(n,m,m);
w = rand(n,1);
tic;
B = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,w,A),1));
toc;
```

The line where `B` is assigned runs in about 0.9 seconds on my machine (Matlab R2012b, MacBook Pro 13" retina, 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5, 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3). It should be noted that for my problem, the tensor `A` will be the same (constant) for the whole run of the program (after initialization), but w can take any values. Also, typical values of `n` and `m` are used here, meaning that the tensor `A` will have a size of about 1 GB in memory.

The clearest way I can think of writing this in Fortran is something like this:

```
pure function weight_matrices(w,A) result(B)
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n = 46
    integer, parameter :: m = 1800
    double precision, dimension(num_sizes), intent(in) :: w
    double precision, dimension(num_sizes,msize,msize), intent(in) :: A
    double precision, dimension(msize,msize) :: B
    integer :: i
    B = 0
    do i = 1,n
        B = B + w(i)*A(i,:,:)
    end do
end function weight_matrices
```

This function runs in about 1.4 seconds when compiled with gfortran 4.7.2, using -O3 (function call timed with "call cpu_time(t)"). If I manually unwrap the loop into

```
B = w(1)*A(1,:,:)+w(2)*A(2,:,:)+ ... + w(46)*A(46,:,:)
```

the function takes about 0.11 seconds to run instead. This is great and means that I get a speedup of about 8 times compared to the Matlab version. However, I still have some questions on readability and performance.

First, I wonder if there is an even faster way to perform this weighting and summing of matrices. I have looked through BLAS and LAPACK, but can't find any function that seems to fit. I have also tried to put the dimension in `A` that enumerates the matrices as the last dimension (i.e. switching from `(i,j,k)` to `(k,i,j)` for the elements), but this resulted in slower code.

Second, this fast version is not very flexible, and actually looks quite ugly, since it is so much text for such a simple computation. For the tests I am running I would like to try to use different numbers of weights, so that the length of w will vary, to see how it affects the rest of my algorithm. However, that means I quite tedious rewrite of the assignment of `B` every time. Is there any way to make this more flexible, while keeping the performance the same (or better)?

Third, the tensor `A` will, as mentioned before, be constant during the run of the program. I have set constant scalar values in my program using the "parameter" attribute in their own module, importing them with the "use" expression into the functions/subroutines that need them. What is the best way to do the equivalent thing for the tensor `A`? I want to tell the compiler that this tensor will be constant, after init., so that any corresponding optimizations can be done. Note that `A` is typically ~1 GB in size, so it is not practical to enter it directly in the source file.

Thank you in advance for any input! :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could try something like

```
    do k=1,m
       do j=1,m
          B(j,k)=sum( [ ( (w(i)*A(i,j,k)), i=1,n) ])
       enddo
    enddo
```

The square brace is a newer form of (/ /), the 1d matrix (vector). The term in `sum` is a matrix of dimension `(n)` and `sum` sums all of those elements. This is precisely what your unwrapped code does (and is not exactly equal to the `do` loop you have).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I need to learn this kind of notation, with a loop inside the expression. It is quite a bit faster than my loop, at 0.22 seconds, but unfortunately not as fast as the unwrapped code, at 0.12 seconds. So, a factor of two difference still.

Comment: My assumption on the time difference is that my code has to go through every cell of `B` because of the loops whereas your unwrapped code does not. I doubt `forall(k=1:m,j=1:m)` would result in any difference from what I wrote, but it could be worth a shot?

Comment: Sure, I tried it, and it runs in about 0.5 seconds. I think I will try a workaround where I create a number of functions with different number of weights, and then use a vector of pointers to these functions to choose from by index. I hope the compiler will be smart enough to optimize away the extra indirection.

Comment: I figured the `forall` would be slower. Is the optimization really necessary to get it to 0.1 seconds? That is, is this code run a million times (or at least something high) that a 0.1 second difference between the two adds up?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is the critical part of the program. It is part of an objective function for a very difficult minimization problem. I just ran a test in Matlab where the solution was found in ~24 hours. From profiling, it seems like about 95% of the time will be spent doing this weighting. Getting it to 0.1 seconds vs 0.2 should result in a runtime of 3 hours, vs 6 hours. I have other drastic optimizations in mind as well (including optimizing the fitting algorithm, and maybe I can decrease the matrix size, at the cost of precision), but this is an important part.

Comment: That is what I figured, that you will be running this portion a lot for a long time. Have you considered getting Intel's Fortran compiler? I had a code that ran in about 3 hours on gfortran that ran in about 20 minutes using ifort (using `-O3` for both).

Comment: Yes, I have considered that option. But I'm still not sure if this algorithm will work and don't feel like paying yet, for that reason. For now, gfortran will have to do, while I'm testing things out.

Comment: If you are not working for a company and/or not doing this for scientific research, ifort is free. If you are working for a company, see if they'll buy it for you. If you're doing it for science, see if (a) your lab/school has a copy or (b) get a grant for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would not hide any looping as this is usually slower. You can write it explicitely, then you'll see that the inner loop access is over the last index, making it inefficient. So, you should make sure your `n` dimension is the last one by storing A is `A(m,m,n)`:

```
B = 0
do i = 1,n
    w_tmp = w(i)
    do j = 1,m
        do k = 1,m
            B(k,j) = B(k,j) + w_tmp*A(k,j,i)
        end do
    end do
end do
```

this should be much more efficient as you are now accessing consecutive elements in memory in the inner loop.

Another solution is to use the level 1 BLAS subroutines _AXPY (y = a*x + y):

```
B = 0
do i = 1,n
    CALL DAXPY(m*m, w(i), A(1,1,i), 1, B(1,1), 1)
end do
```

With Intel MKL this should be more efficient, but again you should make sure the last index is the one which changes in the outer loop (in this case the loop you're writing). You can find the necessary arguments for this call here: [MKL](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-A491FDF5-ACA0-4EDC-8F74-00306D0EBE05.htm)

EDIT: you might also want to use some parallellization? (I don't know if Matlab takes advantage of that)

EDIT2: In the answer of Kyle, the inner loop is over different values of `w`, which is more efficient than `n` times reloading `B` as `w` can be kept in cache (using `A(n,m,m)`):

```
B = 0
do i = 1,m
    do j = 1,m
        B(j,i)=0.0d0
        do k = 1,n
            B(j,i) = B(j,i) + w(k)*A(k,j,i)
        end do
    end do
end do
```

This explicit looping performs about 10% better as the code of Kyle which uses whole-array operations. Bandwidth with `ifort -O3 -xHost` is ~6600 MB/s, with `gfortran -O3` it's ~6000 MB/s, and the whole-array version with either compiler is also around 6000 MB/s.

Comment: Fortran is column major! You want the left most index of an array on the **inside** of multiple do loops!

Comment: I tried both your alternatives but they end up running at ~0.2 seconds, so half as fast as the manually unrolled version. I wonder if I have missed something when compiling. Is there a way to turn off runtime bounds checking in gfortran? Running with and without -fcheck=bounds makes no difference in performance. @KyleKanos: Isn't that exactly what steabert did?

Comment: And yes, I will use some parallelization eventually, but I thought it would be better to run a batch (>=2) of these functions in parallel instead of trying to incorporate parallelization inside each "instance" of the function. Matlab's support for multithreading is quite poor, but supposedly bsxfun applies the supplied function in parallel if the data set is large enough.

Comment: I would think MKL BLAS is fastest, it surprises me it isn't. For best speed, you should try to let the compiler do loop unrolling, e.g. my try would be sth like `gfortran -O2 -funroll-loops`

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that I unfortunately don't have access to Intel's MKL, but used the BLAS provided by ATLAS in the MacPorts repository.

Comment: @KyleKanos: that's what I did, I just wanted to correct on the loop as the OP wrote it. Your alternative is also correct, just different amount of load/store of B compared to w (which I think might make a difference depending on the size of B or w, but I guess it's difficult to know this beforehand).

Comment: Unfortunately -funroll-loops (with -O2 or -O3) does not affect performance. Anyway, I much appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: No problem. For me, Kyle's solutions runs twice as fast, which is probably due to the fact that it loads elements of B only once, and that w is much smaller (but apparently on your hardware the performance is the same).

Comment: Okay, good to know. I guess you use Intel's compiler? If the program ends up working as intended, it will probably worth it investing in a better compiler.

Comment: I actually use gfortran most of the time, as it is quite good. Just for BLAS I always use MKL on Intel hardware.

Comment: Ooops! I didn't notice the reversal of indices on A in the first code snippet. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to refine Kyle Vanos' solution.

Therefor I decided to use `sum` and Fortran's vector-capabilities.

*I don't know, if the results are correct, because I only looked for the timings!*

**Version 1:** (for comparison)

```
B = 0
do i = 1,n
    B = B + w(i)*A(i,:,:)
end do
```

**Version 2:** (from Kyle Vanos)

```
do k=1,m
   do j=1,m
      B(j,k)=sum( [ ( (w(i)*A(i,j,k)), i=1,n) ])
   enddo
enddo
```

**Version 3:** (mixed-up indices, work on one row/column at a time)

```
do j = 1, m
    B(:,j)=sum( [ ( (w(i)*A(:,i,j)), i=1,n) ], dim=1)
enddo
```

**Version 4:** (complete matrices)

```
B=sum( [ ( (w(i)*A(:,:,i)), i=1,n) ], dim=1)
```

**Timing**

As you can see, I had to mixup the indices to get faster execution times. The third solution is really strange because the number of the matrix is the middle index, but this is necessary for memory-order-reasons.

```
V1: 1.30s
V2: 0.16s
V3: 0.02s
V4: 0.03s
```

Concluding, I would say, that you can get a massive speedup, if you have the possibility to change order of the matrix indices in arbitrary order.

Comment: It seems like compilers (and perhaps processors/memory speed?) play a large role here. For me, v2 comes out at ~0.2 seconds, v3 at ~0.3 seconds and v4 at ~0.9 seconds, vs ~0.12 seconds for the manually unrolled one. Seems like I need to get my hands on ifort. :)

Comment: @imladris: if you are using Intel CPUs then yes, you do need to get your hands on ifort.  For speed of execution on Intel hardware the Intel compiler wins (see http://www.polyhedron.com/compare0html).  Other compilers have their strengths too though.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark In none of these versions is `m` an index variable. So I don't know, what you mean.

Comment: What I mean @Stefan is that I am a blockhead and completely misread your code.  I've removed my mis-comment.

Comment: @imladris I used `ifort test.f90 -O3 -mkl`. I used the Intel MKL to measure the time with `dsecnd`. The code is executed on a Intel Core i5-750 so the Intel specific optimizations can be extremely fast.

Comment: You should be careful, as I think your version 3/4 code might be wrong. On my computer, the 'Kyle' code achieves maxmimum memory bandwidth, your code achieves some impossible bandwidth with a different matrix B in the end...

Comment: Hmm, I didn't see the different ordering in code 3. However, if I fix that, the result is still wrong and the code much slower :)

Comment: @steabert I explicitly noted, that you have to change the ordering of your indices (first paragraph of section *timing*). I also said in the third line of my post, that I don't know if the results are correct since I only cared for the speed of the implementation to provide a hint for the OP, what to try next.

Comment: @steabert In which way did you "fix" the indices. If you changed them only in my code, it is obvious, that the timing is worse, because the memory access is not as linear as possible anymore.

Comment: @Stefan: with 'fixing' I only referred to the fact that my first comment was incorrect: I had not properly implemented your solution 3. However, when I did implement it correctly like you wrote it, it doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to do, and it's much slower than either of the correct ones. Just providing a hint on what to try next is perfectly fine, but if you claim certain performance improvements in your answer, you should be sure they actually do the right thing, so could you check that?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, however I will be glad to bring my contribution as I played with most of the posted solutions.

By adding a local unroll for the weights loop (from Steabert's answer ) gives me a little speed-up compared to the complete unroll version (from 10% to 80% with different size of the matrices). The partial unrolling may help the compiler to vectorize the 4 operations in one SSE call.

```
pure function weight_matrices_partial_unroll_4(w,A) result(B)
  implicit none
  integer, parameter  :: n = 46
  integer, parameter  :: m = 1800
  real(8), intent(in) :: w(n)
  real(8), intent(in) :: A(n,m,m)
  real(8)             :: B(m,m)
  real(8)             :: Btemp(4)
  integer             :: i, j, k, l, ndiv, nmod, roll
  !==================================================
  roll = 4
  ndiv = n / roll
  nmod = mod( n, roll )

  do i = 1,m
    do j = 1,m
        B(j,i)=0.0d0
        k = 1
        do l = 1,ndiv
          Btemp(1) = w(k  )*A(k  ,j,i)
          Btemp(2) = w(k+1)*A(k+1,j,i)
          Btemp(3) = w(k+2)*A(k+2,j,i)
          Btemp(4) = w(k+3)*A(k+3,j,i)
          k = k + roll
          B(j,i) = B(j,i) + sum( Btemp )
        end do

        do l = 1,nmod !---- process the rest of the loop
          B(j,i) = B(j,i) + w(k)*A(k,j,i)
          k = k + 1
        enddo
    end do
  end do
end function
```